# fmap into a do block fails with a print error

Tags: haskell, monads, io-monad, do-notation

I'm trying to understand why a function I have written with a do-block can't be rewritten to fmap a similar lambda expression over a list.

I have the following:

```
-- This works
test1 x = do 
        let m = T.pack $ show x
        T.putStrLn m

test1 1
```

Produces

```
1
```

But

```
-- This fails
fmap (\x -> do 
              let m = T.pack $ show x
              T.putStrLn m
              ) [1..10]

-- And this also fails
fmap (\x -> do 
             T.putStrLn $ T.pack $ show x
                ) [1..10]
```

With error:

```
<interactive>:1:1: error:
    • No instance for (Show (IO ())) arising from a use of ‘print’
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

My putStrLn is consistent between the working and the non-working.  The imports are the same.  My show-pack-putstrln dance required to print is also consistent between the working and the non-working.

What is happening that the use of print is changing between the working and non-working?

### Update 1

```
-- I was also surprised that this fails
fmap (T.putStrLn $ T.pack $ show) [1..10]
-- it seemed as similar as possible to the test1 function but mapped.

<interactive>:1:7: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Integer -> b’ with actual type ‘IO ()’
    • In the first argument of ‘fmap’, namely ‘(T.putStrLn $ pack $ show)’
      In the expression: fmap (T.putStrLn $ pack $ show) [1 .. 10]
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = fmap (T.putStrLn $ pack $ show) [1 .. 10]
    • Relevant bindings include it :: [b] (bound at <interactive>:1:1)
<interactive>:1:29: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘() -> String’ with ‘String’
      Expected type: String
        Actual type: () -> String
    • Probable cause: ‘show’ is applied to too few arguments
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘show’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘pack $ show’
      In the first argument of ‘fmap’, namely ‘(T.putStrLn $ pack $ show)’
```

### Update 2

```
-- This lambda returns x of the same type as \x
-- even while incidentally printing along the way
fmap (\x -> do 
              let m = T.pack $ show x
              T.putStrLn $ m
              return x
              ) [1..10]
```

But also fails with:

```
<interactive>:1:1: error:
    • No instance for (Show (IO Integer)) arising from a use of ‘print’
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `fmap f [1..10]` is `[T]` where `T` is the return type of `f`.

In your case, `T = IO ()`, so the type of the full expression is `[IO ()]`.

IO actions can not be printed, so GHCi complains when you try to print that list. You might want to run those actions instead of printing them, using something like `sequence_ (fmap f [1..10])`.

Alternatively, consider ditching `fmap` and instead using something like

```
import Data.Foldable (for_)

main = do
   putStrLn "hello"
   for_ [1..10] $ \i -> do
      putStrLn "in the loop"
      print (i*2)
   putStrLn "out of the loop"
```

Comment: Thank you, and this is helpful, but when I change the return type of the lambda to be the same as the x that comes in as \x as I do in the update 2 and just do the print as incidental rather than the return, I still get the same error.  I understand your for_ loop is correct, but why does my revised fmap not work like the function I am replacing up top?

Comment: @Mittenchops `fmap` on a list produces a list. Your original code did not involve any lists. Try asking GHCi about the type of your expressions, you will see that they are of type `[IO ()]` instead of `IO something`, so you need `sequence_` if you want to actually run the list of IO actions.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> but when I change the return type of the lambda to be the same as the x that comes in as \x as I do in the update 2 ...

No, no. You don't. A lambda function returns the value of its *last expression*. Your lambda function has just *one* expression in it -- *the entire `do { ... }` block* defines a value, which is that lambda function's return value. Not `x`. The `return` belongs to the `do`, not the lambda expression. It is easier to see if we write it with the explicit separators, as

```
fmap (\x -> do {
              let m = T.pack $ show x ;
              T.putStrLn $ m ;
              return x
              } ) [1..10]
```

The `do` block as a whole has the same monadic type as each of its line statements.

One of those is `putStrLn ...`, whose type is `IO ()`. So your lambda function returns `IO t` for some `t`.

And because of `return x`, `t` is the type of `x`. We have `return :: Monad m => t -> m t`, so with `m ~ IO` it is `return :: t -> IO t`.

`x` comes from the argument list `Num t => [t]`, so overall you have

```
Num t => fmap (fx :: t -> IO t) (xs :: [t]) :: [IO t]
```

or

```
           xs :: [t]
        fx    ::  t  ->  IO t
   ----------------------------
   fmap fx xs ::        [IO t]
```

Comment: This is a very helpful explanation.  Thank you!