# Changing the order of arguments for function and list with flip in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have the following (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55854047/1052117)):

```
for_ [1..10] $ (\x -> T.putStrLn $ T.pack $ show x )
```

I'm trying to rewrite this in terms more like

```
applylike myfunction toList
```

rather than

```
applylike tolist myfunction
```

I understand the [flip function can be employed to change argument order](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:flip):

> ```
> flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
> ```
>
> flip f takes its (first) two arguments in the reverse order of f.
>
> ```
> >>> flip (++) "hello" "world"
> "worldhello"
> ```

This works as my original:

```
import Data.Foldable (for_)

:t flip
-- 1
for_ [1..10] $ (\x -> T.putStrLn $ T.pack $ show x )
-- success
```

But when I try to apply it directly, this fails:

```
-- 2
flip for_ $ (\x -> T.putStrLn $ T.pack $ show x ) [1..10] 
-- fail
```

I notice, however, that if I remove the `$` operator which was required in (1), it succeeds:

```
-- 3
flip for_ (\x -> T.putStrLn $ T.pack $ show x ) [1..10] 
-- success
```

But I don't understand why that scans correctly.  When I remove the $ operator from the original non-flipped version (1), that also fails.

```
-- 4    
for_ [1..10] (\x -> T.putStrLn $ T.pack $ show x )
-- fail
```

How are these being parsed that `$` is required in (1) and required not to be present in (3)?

### Update

Apologies: `4` above does succeed.  I must have had a typo while investigating this, which certainly added to my confusion.  For future readers, `4` does not fail and the universe makes more sense, and both comments and the answer accepted below were very helpful in this investigation.

Comment: Don't you just want `traverse`? ([Literally](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#for_), `for_ = flip traverse`).

Comment: I may want to do that, but I also want to understand what's happening with the order of function application here.

Comment: How does (4) fail for you? It works just fine here.

Comment: very thorough investigation! case (4) succeeds though.

Comment: Thank you, I've added an update note on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because that's how the `$` operator works. This operator is not part of Haskell syntax, but a regular user-defined operator, like any other. It's defined like this:

```
f $ x = f x
```

Therefore, if you write something like:

```
f a $ b
```

That is the same as:

```
f a b
```

But if you write something like:

```
f $ a b
```

That is the same as:

```
f (a b)
```

This is because function application `a b` (i.e. function `a` applied to argument `b`) has the highest precedence in Haskell, nothing can bind stronger than the function application, including the `$` operator.

Therefore, your first attempt:

```
flip for_ $ (\x -> T.putStrLn $ T.pack $ show x ) [1..10]
```

Is really equivalent to:

```
flip for_ ( (\x -> T.putStrLn $ T.pack $ show x ) [1..10] )
```

Which is clearly not what you meant.

Comment: a side note, ($) actually binds the weakest: `*Main> :i ($)` says `infixr 0 $` i.e. level 0, while the functional application (i.e. "space") binds at the level 10.